# Parse json column value in CSV file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file with the below format:
[image]

where column c3 is of JSON format. I need to parse that Json value to different columns and generate a CSV file.
I am using parse functionlaity :

[image]

But I am getting the below error:

[image]

Can someone help me identify whether I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like you have selected **Document per line** under JSON settings in Parse transformation. As your file contains single JSON, change the settings to select **Single document**. (By default, document form is selected as Document per line).

   I tried the sample by selecting Document per line and got same error as you. After changing the settings to **Single document**, I can preview data without errors.

[image]

Changed the JSON settings:
[image]

2. Make sure the format is a valid JSON.

   The format of c3 column in your file is not exactly in JSON format. When you preview data, the value is not parsed and shown as NULL/blank data in parsed columns.

[image]

I tried parsing with valid JSON format and it’s working fine.

Example of JSON data format looks like:

`{"Name": "None", "status": "None", "processdby": 2}`

[image]

Reference: [Parse transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse)